# How to set expiry for ActiveStorage URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, rails-activestorage

So according to the official Rails [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#serving-files), the URLs for viewing the stored files are permanent and there is no way to expire them.

The URLs that are generated using `rails_blob_path` and `rails_storage_proxy_path`.

If someone knows `blob_id` and `filename` of an object, the URLs can be generated.

Is there a workaround to set the expiry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following would be helpful:

```
# signed URL with expiration
rails_blob_path(user.avatar, disposition: "attachment", expires_in: 10.minutes)

# or

# set a default expiration time in config/application.rb
module Blog
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.active_storage.urls_expire_in = 30.minutes
  end
end
```

For more details, you can visit [here](https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/09/14/rails-7-adds-expiring-urls-to-active-storage/)